# Finding a class $C$ of bipartite PPT states such that entanglement of $\rho \in C$ implies entanglement of $\rho + \rho^{\Gamma}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, mathematical-physics, positive-semidefinite, quantum-information

Consider an entangled bipartite quantum state $\rho \in \mathcal{M}_d(\mathbb{C}) \otimes \mathcal{M}_{d'}(\mathbb{C})$ which is positive under partial transposition, i.e., $\rho^\Gamma \geq 0$. As separability of $\rho$ is equivalent to separability of its partial transpose $\rho^\Gamma$, we know that $\rho^\Gamma$ is entangled. What are the conditions on $\rho$ which will guarantee that the sum $\rho + \rho^\Gamma$ (ignoring trace normalization) is also entangled?

It turns out that the above proposition does not hold for arbitrary PPT entangled states. Easiest counterexamples can be found in $\mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{C}) \otimes \mathcal{M}_{d}(\mathbb{C})$, where $\rho + \rho^\Gamma$ is separable for all quantum states $\rho \in \mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{C}) \otimes \mathcal{M}_d(\mathbb{C})$ (see [separability in 2xN systems](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9903012.pdf)).

In the language of entanglement witnesses, the problem reduces to finding a common witness that detects both $\rho$ and $\rho^\Gamma$. Let $W$ be the entanglement witness detecting $\rho$, i.e., $\text{Tr} (W\rho) < 0$. Then $W$ is non-decomposable (as $\rho$ is PPT) and is of the canonical form $P+Q^\Gamma - \epsilon \mathbb{I}$, where $P, Q \geq 0$ are such that $\text{range}(P) \subseteq\text{ker}(\delta)$ and $\text{range}(Q) \subseteq \text{ker}(\delta^\Gamma)$ for some bipartite edge state $\delta$ (these are special states that violate the range criterion for separability in an extreme manner, see [edge states](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.63.044304)) and $0 < \epsilon \leq \text{inf}_{|e,f\rangle} \langle e,f | P+Q^\Gamma | e,f \rangle$. If $\delta$ is such that $\text{ker}(\delta) \cap \text{ker}(\delta^\Gamma)$ is not empty, then we can choose $P=Q$ to be the orthogonal projector on $\text{ker}(\delta) \cap \text{ker}(\delta^\Gamma)$, in which case $W=W^\Gamma$ is the common witness. Can we find a class of PPT entangled states for which the previous statement holds? Can optimization of entanglement witnesses be somehow used to ensure this condition?

---

***[Cross-posted on physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/565067/58382)***

***[Cross-posted on quantumcomputing.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/565067/58382)***

Comment: Have you tried testing your conjecture on known families of entangled, PPT states?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom So the problem is that for a given entangled PPT state, I don't think there's an easy way to bring its witness in the canonical form. So the approach I've mentioned is a little hard to implement in practice.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom However, if the state in question is already an edge state, we simply need to compute the kernel of the state itself and its partial transpose. I've tried this for a couple of states in dimension $d=d'=3$, but it doesn't work. But, given the witness, there's still hope for optimizing it (increasing the set of states that it detects) in such a way that it detects the partial transpose.

Comment: By "testing your conjecture," I meant taking a non-entangled PPT state $\rho$ and checking whether $\rho + \rho^{\Gamma}$ is entangled, which if I recall correctly can be checked with semidefinite programming

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Well, if $\rho$ is non-entangled, i.e., separable, then $\rho^\Gamma$ is separable and so the sum $\rho + \rho^\Gamma$ is trivially separable (due to convexity). So there's nothing to test here. The non-trivial part is when $\rho$ is entangled because then, the sum can either be entangled or separable,  depending on whether a common witness exists.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say an **entangled** PPT state $\rho$; "non-separable" and "entangled" got mixed together there.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I have tested it for a few families of entangled PPT states with some specialized tests for separability and have not found a counterexample yet. But I agree that semidefinite programming hierarchies are more robust and broad in their scope to detect entanglement. I'll certainly try and see if this leads to a rebuttal. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Not to shy you away (I think this question is fine for MSE), but you might have more sucess on quantum computing stackexchange: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/ If you decide to post there, wait a few more days (since you already posted on two stacks) and link the other versions.

Comment: @MaoWao Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I agree that the question will be of more relevance there. I didn't know that quantum computing SE existed tbh.